# Django Model Relationships Across Multiple Models

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

- Posts
- Candidates
- Departments
- Applications

Within the the Applications model I have the following:

```
department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
application_received = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
post_filled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My question is two fold:

1. How do I create a relationship back to the post when it is filled?
2. How to I add the detail to the candidate model that they have filled
   that post?

At the moment using the applications model provides all the relevant detail.
I have looked at this for so long I can't see the wood for the trees so any help, or even why are you doing it that way, would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for the reverse link to Post model from Application model? Like you want to access the the posts of that application?

Comment: Basically I am looking to enter that the candidate has been successful in both the posts and the candidates models.